# SQLite3 table update not reflected in simulator/user folder

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, ios5, sqlite

I was able to successfully create and access my database. However, when I needed to change an attribute's type later, I modified my project's folder database and then added the new database to Xcode. When I run my app now (although I've deleted the app's directory from the simulator) I still get my old database!

I even tried to alter the table programmatically as follows:

```
NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TTSData.sql"];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
//
sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
if(sqlite3_open([defaultDBPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE Patient ALTER COLUMN Result DOUBLE"];
    const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    if(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Success" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];    
        [alert show];
        alert=nil;
    }
    else 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Not Altered" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];   
        [alert show];
        alert=nil;
    }   
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);    
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

But I still get my old database. Does anyone have a clue of what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: You can't alter your database programmatically because despite copying it to a writable location, you still `sqlite3_open([defaultDBPath UTF8String])`...

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I realize now that it was stupid of me to do that, but I was helpless I tried everything I still don't know what's the problem. Would posting my create database method help?

Comment: nope just change that path and see what happens.

Comment: @H2CO3 What path? you mean the name of my database?

Comment: nope, the one on sqlite3_open.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to alter your DB in resource. :(